# $.ajaxまたは$.getを用いてデータを取得する方法

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQueryで次のようなスクリプトを記述したところ、次のような結果になりました。

```
//jQuery記述
$(".Content").load("data/test.txt");

$.get("data/test.txt",function (data, status){
    $(".Content").append(data);
},"txt");

$.ajax({
    url:"data/test.txt"
})
.then(
    function (data) {
        $(".Content").append(data);
    },
    function () {
        $(".Content").append("読込失敗");
    }
);
//txt内容(文字コードはUTF-8)
読込成功
//結果
<div class="Content">読込成功読込失敗</div>
```

上記の結果から、.loadによるデータの取得は成功しており、.ajaxと.getによるデータの取得は失敗しているものと思われます。
私は.ajaxでデータを取得したいのですが、どのようにすればそれが可能でしょうか？

どうぞ、宜しくお願い致します。

3/26　10:24 追記
FireFoxの開発者ツールでコンソールを確認してみたところ、下記のエラーが出ておりました。

```
整形式になっていません。 test.txt:1:3
整形式になっていません。 test.htm:1:3
```

また、SabaMotto様のご指摘を受けて次のようにjQueryの記述を修正したところ、結果は下記のようになりました。

```
//jQuery記述
$(".Content").load("data/test.txt");

$.get("data/test.txt",function (data, status){
    $(".Content").append(data);
},"text");

$.ajax({
    url:"data/test.txt",
    dataType:"text"
})
.then(
    function (data) {
        $(".Content").append(data);
    },
    function () {
        $(".Content").append("読込失敗");
    }
);
//結果
<div class="Content">読込成功読込成功読込成功</div>
```

上記の結果より、$.get及び$.ajaxによるデータの取得が成功したと思われるので、この質問は解決済みとさせて頂きます。

Comment: $.getの第3引数ですが、テキストのデータ形式は"text"です。開発ツールのコンソールなどにエラーは出ていませんか？もしあればタグの下にある編集から質問に書き加えてください。

Answer (score 1):

コメントした第3引数で解決されたようなので、補足付きで回答しておきます。

`$.get` `$.post` `$.ajax`のdataTypeで指定できるものは次の6種類です。

- "xml"
- "html"
- "script"
- "json"
- "jsonp"
- "text"
- デフォルト："xml", "html", "script", "json"から自動で判断される

今回のようにプレーンテキストを取得する場合は、自動で判別されないため明示的に"text"を指定しなければなりません。

参考 : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/